# (javascript) How to point from a single cell to the all the cell in a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this simple code that ask for passwords when somebody selects names from a dropdown menu (data validation) my problem is it only directs it to a single cell, what should i add or do to make it point to all the cells in a column? please see below.

```js
// define each user password
const userPasswords = { 
  "Guilherme Cudessuata": "123",
  "Manuel Jose": "456",
  "Emaculada": "789",
  "Jonata Kedia": "111"
  }

function onEdit(e) {
  const namesCell = "E4" // the cell with the dropdown
  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != namesCell) {
    return
  }

  // show prompt for password:
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  const response = ui.prompt("Password protected range", 
    "Please enter your password:",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)

  const button = response.getSelectedButton()
  const text = response.getResponseText() 

  // don't run if the user pressed cancel or close
  if (button != ui.Button.OK) {
    return
  }

  // check the passwords
  if (text != userPasswords[e.value]) {
    ui.alert('Incorrect Password', 'Please try again', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue) // reset to old value
  }
}
```

Comment: try this `... const namesCol =5; if (e.range.columnStart != namesCol ) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const sheetName = "Sheet1" //change to suit
  const namesColumn = 5 // the column with the dropdown
  const startRow = 4 //change to suit
  const endRow = 100 //change to suit

  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != sheetName || e.range.columnStart != namesColumn || e.range.rowStart < startRow || 
  e.range.rowEnd > endRow) {
    return;
  }

  //rest of your code
}
```

... and see if that helps?

#### Reference:

- [Event objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)